# Improving time in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test")
    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
         For i = LBound(sPrincipal) To (UBound(sPrincipal) - 3) 
                 .Cells((Lastrow + 1), 1) = sPrincipal(i)
                 .Cells((Lastrow + 1), 2) = sInterest(i)
                 .Cells((Lastrow + 1), 3) = sBalance(i)
                  Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
         Next i
End With
```

There are around 100 thousand rows(also more columns than shown here) that I need to fill up regularly and need to speed this up as this takes me more than 2-3 hours. Can anyone advice if there is a way to speed the process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `sPrinciple`?  Range?  Array?  Variant? are the other variables the same type?

Comment: The slow bit of your code would be interacting with the sheet, read it all into an array and then output to your sheet as one interaction. you could also use screnupdating and calculate but remember to turn them back on after

Comment: @Degustaf Sorry for not mentioning that. They are all Arrays.

Comment: Instead of looping through all the cells, you should be able to use three separate with blocks to assign the values all at once.

Comment: @99moorem I always turnoff the screen updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dim entries as Integer

entries = UBound(sPrinciple) - LBound(sPrinciple)
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test")
    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells((Lastrow + 1), 1).Resize(entries, 1).Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.Transpose(sPrinciple)
    .Cells((Lastrow + 1), 2).Resize(entries, 1).Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.Transpose(sInterest)
    .Cells((Lastrow + 1), 3).Resize(entries, 1).Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.Transpose(sBalance)
End With
```

This does have the drawback that you can only paste 65536 rows at a time (the Excel 2003 row limit.  I would recommend running your code in batches where it processes that many rows at a time until you finish the entire data set.